# Additional arguments in a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

How do i check for what additional arguments can be passed in a function in R. For example, i recently discovered an additional argument character.only for lapply function.

```
packageslist <- list('car', 'MASS')
lapply(packageslist, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

Comment: `formalArgs(fun)`? `args(fun)`? `help(fun)`?  Btw, `character.only` is an argument of `require` there, not `lapply`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the list of arguments with

```
args(function)
```

Notice that, when you do that for `lapply`, you get:

```
args(lapply)

function (X, FUN, ...)
```

Those three dots (...) mean that you can add optional arguments to the function that you pass as an argument to `lapply`, so there can be extra arguments that are not directly arguments for `lapply`.